# Recommended way to inherit nodeJs's request Object in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

What the the best way to inherit a complex Object or class down to every ReactJS-Component ?

As described on their documentation its not recommended to use context and I guess using the prop will also not the best solution.

This is our case:

*Edit: Maybe a better example is when we try to inherit the request object from router into the 20th level of children for SSR reasons*

We are using a Router which works on client and also for SSR. For every route which gets rendered we need on client and server a generated class to work with. So one solution should look like this:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myAwesomeObject = new AwesomeClass({/* some settings */});
  }
  getChildContext() {
    let { myAwesomeObject } = this;
    return {
      myAwesomeObject
    };
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <span><ComponentLevel1 /></span>
    );
  }
}

const ComponentLevel1 = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ComponentLevel2 />
    </div>
  );
};
const ComponentLevel2 = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ComponentLevel3 />
    </div>
  );
};
......
const ComponentLevel20 = (props) => {
  content = this.context.myAwesomeObject.doSomeThingWithProps(props);
  return (
    <div>
      {content}
    </div>
  );
};
```

In this example I am now able to use the awesomeObject in every Component I will render but the context is not recommended by ReactJS:
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html

So my question now is: What is the best recommended way to inherit classes like that down to all components ?

I know: on client this is not a problem because I can create the object once and use it on client global but on server (SSR) I also need access to the created class. And recreating the object every time I need it in another component seems not to be the best solution - also not to add this class to any component as property - right ?

**EDIT**
I have edited the code snippet to show that it maybe has a case where the 20th level of my children needs access to the instance. With context it would work like in my example but ReactJS says its not recommended. So the other solution would be to add the class to the properties of my children  - 20 levels down - but is this really the best recommended solution to solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

What about composition? (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html)

```
class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <SomeOtherComponent {...this.props} />
        )
    }
}
```

By passing all the props down to different component (including it's children) you can easily customize child component behavior.

Comment: So when my component which is needed this class in the 20th level I have to add the class 20 times to each children until I reached the one which needs the class ? Or is there another way to solve that ?